# I am watching a java tutorial on youtube and can't seem to find I difference between my HandlerClass and itemStateChaged

Tags: java

I watched the tutorial and in it it says the item listener runs the handler class when an action happens but if that is the case why do we need the itemStateChaged. This is not the complete code by the way.

```
    pf = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14);
    bf = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,14);
    itf = new Font("Serif",Font.ITALIC,14);
    bif = new Font("Serif",Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD,14);
    tf.setFont(pf);

    //wait for event to happen, pass in font object to constructor
    pb.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(pf));
    bb.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(bf));
    ib.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(itf));
    bib.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(bif));

}

private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener{
    private Font font;

    public HandlerClass(Font f) {
        font  = f;
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        tf.setFont(font);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemListner is Java Interface with one itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) method (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html)
Therefore, every HandlerClass which implements ItemListener has to provide      itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) implementation.

Using addItemListener(new HandlerClass()) you register your listener for an item.
itemStateChanged() is called when an item has been selected or deselected by the user. The code written in this method performs the operations that need to occur when an item is selected (or deselected).